# Solving Inner-Product Equation (simple)

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Given an inner product space $(V, \langle \cdot \rangle)$.
Given $x, y \in V$,  linearly independent and $\Vert x \Vert = \Vert y \Vert$.

I want to find all $z$ such that
$$\langle x,z \rangle = \langle y,z \rangle.$$

If $V$ is 2-dimensional, z lies on a line with $\frac{x+y}{2}$ as a direction vector. If $V$ is 3-dimensional, z lies on a plane with $x-y$ as a normal vector.
What if $V$ is infinite dimensional?

Of course if we choose $z \perp x$ and $z \perp y$, we got $\langle x,z\rangle = 0 = \langle y,z\rangle$.
Any other $z$ that fulfill the condition?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: $\langle x,z \rangle = \langle y,z \rangle \iff (x-y) \perp z.$

Comment: I see, so I must choose
$z \in span(x-y)^\perp$